# Run the JUnitServllet for integration testing in Adobe cq5

Tags: aem

My question is for the JUnitServlet for integration testing in Adobe cq5. When it runs the tests and if there is a mistake in the test method it shows only error messages from his side. How can we see the messages that we write in the test method assertations.

For example:

If I have several "assertNotNull" in the test method and if the test fails the servlet shows me such a result:

Test finished: () : Null

I tried to enter in depth:

Test selector: RequestParser, testSelector [testClass], methodName [testMethod], extension [html]

but again it runs the whole class with thests.

Can I somehow run just one testing method from the testing class and see the messages from the assertations with this servlet? Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with the Sling integration test sample at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/samples/integration-tests/ ? That would allow for better narrowing it down IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try structuring your assertions inside a try/catch block--at least initially--where you can print out additional info if it fails.  I've found this to provide more useful info when I have a problem in the test itself that is getting masked in the unit test output.  If that is the issue perhaps you won't need to narrow in on a single test.

```
@Test
public void testYourTestName() throws Exception {
    try {
       //Code to prepare the object to be tested
        assertNull("This is my null test", objectToBeTested);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String failureMessage = "\n" + e.toString() + "\n";
        for (StackTraceElement stackLine : e.getStackTrace()) {
            failureMessage += (stackLine.toString() + "\n");
        }
        fail("Error: " + failureMessage);
    }
}
```

Or, you could use an assertEquals test which I have found to have a little more helpful display, such as this:

```
assertEquals(null, objectToBeTested);
```

If the assertEquals above fails, you get output such as this:

> testMyTestName(com.myCompany.myApp.myPath.myTests): expected:<null>
>   but was:<java.lang.Object@5c9e4d73>

BTW, I don't know how to run just one of the tests that exists in some class, but as you have found, you can narrow it down to run all the tests in a particular class.  To run the tests found in the SomeTestClass in the com.myCompany.myApp.myPath namespace:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/sling/junit/com.myCompany.myApp.myPath.SomeTestClass.html
```